# How to find a line of text that does not contain the colon symbol using perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

For example, I'm trying not to find lines of text with the following

```
    !dkdkdkdkdk: dkdkdkdkdkdkdkadfkldllsls  <------ do not find this line of code

    !dksdjfslfjlk afldajfdklafjdla;fd        <-------- find this line of code
```

I tried the following code but not working.

```
           ^!(?!:)*$
```

Comment: `!` is not a "not" operator in regexes... `$foo !~ /:/`, perhaps?

Comment: @MarcB It looks like they're trying to match text that begins with a literal `!`, not negate the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a multiline input, you need to read the data in line by line and check if each line starts with `!` and does not contain `:` with the following regex:

```
/^![^:]*$/
```

Or if you want to split conditions:

```
if (/^!/ and not /:/)
```

The character class `[^:]` will match any character other than a `:`.

Here is working sample:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @matches;
while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^![^:]*$/) {
        push @matches, $_;
        print "$_\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
!dkdkdkdkdk: dkdkdkdkdkdkdkadfkldllsls
!dksdjfslfjlk afldajfdklafjdla;fd
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/b0sh0W)

The `@matches` will contain all the lines that passed the test.

Comment: Note that your regex `^!(?!:)*$` only finds `!` in `!\nSome text`. And although it is not an error in Perl, in many other flavors it is not a valid regex pattern (due to `*` quantifier applied to a look-around).

Comment: Note that `$&` will do horrible things to your script's performance (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665722/is-1-or-faster-for-replacing-a-matched-string-using-s-in-perl); using it makes *every* regex run much slower. In this case you want the whole line you matched, so just use it: `$string`. In this tiny script it wont matter as much, but using it in a module (say) will mess up every script that uses that module as well. Best to get out of the habit of using it, and learn how to use parens and non-capturing parens in your regex instead.

Comment: @dan1111: I had no idea about any complications about using `$&` back-reference, it is totally ok in JS and C# where I am using it extensively because capturing groups IMHO take more resources than non-capturing ones. The snippet I had was a **mere demo**, I only used it to show how the regex works. I changed the demo code and hope it now OK.

Comment: @JoeMcMahon: I have fixed the `$&` issue that I was unaware of, and modified the code so that it could be extrapolated to a more complex task.

Comment: @BruceWalker Please check the update. If it no longer works for you please let me know.

Comment: Yep, that was totally not to criticize -- it's not something that on the face of it says "use this feature to mess up your performance" will be the result. Just wanted to pass it on.

Comment: @JoeMcMahon FYI, the performance issues associated with `$&` and friends were [finally fixed in Perl 5.20](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Performance-issues), after a couple of partial fixes/workarounds. I would still use a capturing group instead of `$&`, though.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Is there anything wrong with

```
if ( /^!/ and not /:/ ) { ... }
```

Comment: I think that's a great option. If one was completely regex-phobic, you could even use `index`.