# regular expression to find the first occurance of a number from a given keyword

Tags: regex, perl, pcre, pcregrep

I have a string

> "ZTFN00 identification number is 89320394 and mobile number is +918017828848"

and I want to identify the first occurrence of a number (**89320394** in this case) from the keyword ZTFN. Also, the expression shall not return 00 with the ZTFN and only return the first occurrence of the number.

I tried `\d+(?!ZTFN00)` but it does not work !!

Please suggest

Comment: What tag is really relevant? Try `\b\d+\b` (should work with PCRE at least). BTW, regex engines only return one match, it is up to a concrete language to implement multiple matching. So, if you use appropriate method, only the first match will be returned.

Comment: If your requirement is to match first occurrence of an 8 digit number which 89320394 is try `\d{8}` with `global` turned off otherwise what @WiktorStribiżew suggested is also correct.

Comment: For getting the first number after a word boundary try `^.*?\b\K\d+` [like this](https://regex101.com/r/vT1uT8/2).

Comment: Are you looking for the first isolated digit string after `ZTFN00`? `print / (?: ZTFN00 ){1}+ .*? \b (\d+) \b /x`. Although much of that may be removed, depending on your live data format. You should always post some real-life data so that we can test our solutions before posting them

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
perl -ne '/ZTFN00\D+(\d+)/ && print $1,"\n"' yourfile
```

If your 'number' is always separated by whitespace ( where there 00 after ZTFN isn't) then you can use that as your test:

```
perl -ne 'print m/\b(\d+)\b/,"\n"' yourfile
```

Comment: What's the purpose of using group expression around `\d+` ?

Comment: @noob: Because Perl does not work well/at all with `\g<0>`/`\0`/`$0` like all other languages.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, Perl does have that. It's called `$&`. It's also not what's needed here.

Comment: @ikegami: I forgot to list that one. When I used that `$&` backreference in [one of my Perl answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32661739/3832970) I was heavily downvoted ([direct link to the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661517/how-to-find-a-line-of-text-that-does-not-contain-the-colon-symbol-using-perl-reg/32661739#comment53171515_32661739)).

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, Prior to 5.20, it could slow down other parts of your program, but the variable has existed and worked since ancient times. Perl also has `${^MATCH}`, which doesn't have that problem.

Comment: I know `$&` existed, it is also available in C#, JavaScript, I just forgot to list it.

Comment: "Perl does not work well/at all with `\g<0>`/`\0`/`$0` like all other languages". That statement is completely false, even if you add `$&` to the list.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: For a long time the use of `$&` anywhere in your code put an overhead on every pattern match in the program. There have been various half-hearted fixes, but Perl 5 v20 finally solved the problem. Unless you don't care about performance, or you can guarantee that your program will always be run under Perl 5 v20 or better. you should still avoid using `$&`

Comment: @Borodin: Thank you very much for clarification. I also think that using one capturing group does not hurt performance :)

Comment: @Borodin, Not all matches; just those without captures. Captures already impose the same penalty as `$&` to a match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I agree that the issue of the penalty of using `$&` has been way over-dramatised. For any program that is disk-bound, internet-bound, or keyboard-bound it represents an infinitesimal loss of performance. I think the problem is more to do with this inefficiency in Perl's interpreter being very obvious

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Po 'ZTFN00.*?\K\b\d+\b'
```

Returns the first number that's a between word boundaries in a line where `ZTFN00` is seen before that number. `\K` is a variable length look-behind: "match what's to the left of me, but don't retain it".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys !
In simple term, what I am looking for is this
If there is a string, which has a keyword ZTFN00, then the regex shall be able to return the closest 9 to 11 digit number to the left or right side of the string.

I want to do this in REGEXP_REPLACE function of oracle.

Below are some of the sample strings

1. The following error occurred in the SAP UPDATE_BP service as part of the combine (error:653, R11:186:Number 867278489 Already Exists for ID Type ZTFN00)

In the above, the regex shall return 867278489

2. The following error occurred in the SAP UPDATE_BP service as part of the combine (error:653, R11:186:Number ZTFN00 identification number 123456778 already exist)

In the above, the regex shall return 123456778

Many thanks for sharing your expertise and guidance